# Android content provider modified / created date

Tags: java, android, database, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

In example: If I'm accessing the SMS database, there is a 'Date' field for message timestamp.  However, say I load messages with an older timestamp into the database, how do I know that they were added *after* the later timestamped messages? Is there a modified or created date for table rows that I can access?

Edit and clarification:

The SMS table has the following columns: long _id, thread_id, address, person, date, protocol, read, status, type, reply_path_present, subject, body, service_center, locked,error_code, & seen.

'date' refers to the date which the message was sent, not when it was added to the database. Does the Android database (SQLite) track when data is added or modified in the database? If so, how do I access it? If it does not, and simply add/removes/updates data without logging, that's an answer too.

Comment: Code? errors/logcat? what have you done?, what did your conclude from your research? how did you do it? why you approached it in that manner? etc.. how are we to know what you're talking about? Can you re-edit your question to include full information as possible? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no date in sqlite for when the row was inserted or updated.

Answer (score 3):

you can solve this problem by creating a column containing the current date and time (current means at the moment, the row was inserted):

```
create table mytable(_id int primary key, date datetime default current_timestamp);
```

this will result in a timestamp in every row that points to the moment of insertion

another solution would be simply insert the current timestamp out of the SQLiteOpenHelper like:

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues(2);
values.put(COLUMN_NAME_ID, id);
values.put(COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, title);
values.put(COLUMN_NAME_CREATED_DATE, System.currentTimeMillis());

dbHelper.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```